# Be completed for <date> or be completed on <date>

Tags: prepositions

Could you ensure the work is completed for 20th-Jan? Or
Could you ensure the work is completed on 20th-Jan?
I see a native speaker use "for" and I don't understand why.

Comment: _By Jan 20_ means possibly at any time before then, but definitely at that time.

Answer (score 1):

In those contexts, "for" would imply that the work is needed in order to continue on to the next step, which will happen on the date mentioned.

Example: "Have your worksheet completed for January 20.  On that date, we will use the information on that worksheet as the starting point of the next project."

"On," on the other hand, does not imply that there is a next step starting right away.

Example: "Have your worksheet completed on January 20.  I will collect it.  We may use the worksheet on a later date, but not on January 20."

Comment: "by" is also a possibility.